# textBox.Text shows error doesn't contain a definition in WPF

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

Im trying to show a text in a textbox in WPF.

this is how I added the textbox in the xml :

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBoxLine1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="29,30,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
```

for the C# section of the code :

```
public string getLine1()
        {

            return this.textBoxLine1.Text;
        }
```

> > What this code does: its for a Passport reader it reads the MRZ and displays it in the TextBox. The `textBoxLine1` is undelined with read and gives the bellow error.

```
"FormMRZ" doesnot contain a definition for "textBoxLine1" and no accessible extension method "textBoxLine1" accepting a first argument of type "FormMRZ" could be found
```

How can I fix this error ? I appreciate your help.

**Update:**

My full XML code:

```
<Page x:Class="WpfApp1.Page1"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
      Title="Page1">

    <Grid x:Name="Passport" Background="White">
        <TextBox Name="textBoxLine1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="29,30,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox Name="textBoxLine2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="29,57,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox Name="textBoxLine3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="22" Margin="29,90,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

My FormMRZ Class:

```
public partial class FormMRZ : Form
    {
        private int nbLines;

        public FormMRZ()
        {

        }

        public string MRZInfo, docNumDigit;

        public string getLine1()
        {

            return this.textBoxLine1.Text;
        }

        public string getLine2()
        {
            return this.textBoxLine2.Text;
        }

        public string getLine3()
        {
            return this.textBoxLine3.Text;
        }
}
```

> > This is not the full code for the FormMRZ.

Comment: You can *obviously* not access `this.textBoxLine1` in class FormMRZ, because that is not the Page1 class in which textBoxLine1 is declared. What is the relationship of the two classes? Why do you seemingly have a WinForms Form in a WPF application?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your **.XAML** should be changed

From `<Page x:Class="WpfApp1.Page1"`

To **`<Page x:Class="WpfApp1.FormMRZ">`**

You `XAML` class and `CodeBehind` class should match.

The reason for error is because in your code behind class `FormMRZ` does not have a `XAML` class associated with it and hence no `TextBox` control

**Note:** `FormMRZ` class should belong to `WpfApp1` namespace

Comment: @GG_Programmer_ZZ, can you post your .xaml code especially the namespaces defined at the top

Comment: Check your project for any class file with the same name as `TextBox`. If it exists it will throw this exception, whenever you try to create a TextBox instances.

Comment: and check if `FormMRZ` Class is part of namespace `WpfApp1`

Comment: yes Client it did thank you. But now can I add more than one class to the same name space? on can only one class be in each page??  because when I added ` <Page x:Class="WpfApp1.FormMRZ">` it ignored all the other code in `Page1` as its not recognized by `WpfApp1`

Comment: I think you are using more than 1 Class  to the same XAML class, you should have only 1 XAML Class for One C# Class

Comment: Can you show me an example if you don't mind? as I have already looked for examples and nothing is accurate

Comment: My Page.XAML starts like this `<Page x:Class="WpfApp2.Page1"` and its associated Page.XAML.CS starts like this `namespace WpfApp2{public partial class Page1 : Page {`

Comment: @GG_Programmer_ZZ To get the right solution please show how your `FormMRZ` class relates to your `Page1` class. What are you trying to achieve? You are very likely on the wrong path. Give more insight to provide you with a proper solution.